# Reopen a question that was closed, then changed, and now is missing last reopen vote

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I was directed here to ask about reopening my question after the revisions I made: [Creating necessary documentation for maintenance staff when only Code repository contents can be relied on](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450914/creating-necessary-documentation-for-maintenance-staff-when-only-code-repository)

This was my first question and after many revisions I reached the state where it could actually be good now (it even managed to actually get one decent answer before it was closed). The last revision happened when it was already closed. To the best of my knowledge it has 2 votes to reopen it (though I can't see that), but isn't getting any more views since days and it is stuck like this, and I am really interested to find other options as answers.

Please support.